# Update state on search query in Ant Design AutoComplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I would like to use Ant Design AutoComplete component to fetch data from API. The component has the following code:

```
const Example = ({ token, service }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([])

  const { data } = useFetch(value)

  const onSelect = (data) => {
    console.log('onSelect', data)
  }

  const onChange = (query) => {
    console.log("Search query ", query);
    setValue(query);
    console.log("State value ", value);

    if (value && value.length > 1) {
      setOptions(
        data ? data : []
      )
    } else {
      setOptions([])
    }
  }

  return (
    <AutoComplete
      value={value}
      options={options}
      onSelect={onSelect}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  )
}
```

`data` for the options is provided by `useFetch(value)` hook. So the `value` should be updated as the user types in the input.

But the problem is that `value` in the state is always one character behind the actual search query. Here is the link to my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-autocomplete-7pwsz?file=/index.js:651-746). You can see that `console.log()` for search query and state value are always different. Is there any way to fix that? I need state `value` to be always in synch with the search query.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can make use of `useEffect` which can be used to calls API and update options.

You can do following:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Value"); // This will be in sync with your search.
}, [value])
```

Working sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-usage-autocomplete-forked-eihbw?file=/index.js:369-448